# create cookie in web method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

i have a web method that check user in data base via a jquery-ajax method i wanna if client exists in db i create a cookie in client side with user name but i know that response is not available in staticmethod .how can i create a cookie in a method that call with jquery ajax and must be static. its my code that does not work cuz response is not accesible

```
 if (olduser.Trim() == username.Trim() && password.Trim()==oldpass.Trim())
        { retval =olduser;

        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        context.Session[retval.ToString()] = retval.ToString();
        HttpCookie cook = new HttpCookie("userath");
        cook["submituser"] = "undifiend";
        Response.Cookies.Add(cook);

       }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the Response object in the same way you are accessing the Session object from the current HtppContext.

Your code should end like this:

```
context.Response.Cookies.Add(cook);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the HttpContext into the static method from the Web Method that the AJax call first enters.

EDIT: or, don't use a static method. Either way, the HttpContext will be available from the instanced Web Method that the Ajax call sees via [WebMethod] annotation.

Comment: i dont have problem with session it work properly but i wanna find a solution for create cookie in web method.

Comment: It might help to post some more code, e.g. client side code, to show the context.

Answer (score 0):

1. First make an ajax call. You can read this great tutorial [5 Ways to Make Ajax Calls with jQuery](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/)
2. Second get the server respond. For example if the callback was '1', it means you should set the cookie and if it was '0' you should not.
3. At Last you can easily set the cookie using this jquery plugin: [jquery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).